# Why are there so many underlines in this HTML file? The layout is out of shape too, how to correct it?

Tags: layout, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ｕターンラッシュがピーク　新幹線や空の便、ほぼ満席 -Tenxian</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../common/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<link href="../common/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
.above,div,label,a,td
{
color:black;
}
.price
{
color:red;
}

.below{
margin: 0 12px 0 0; 
}
 li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}
a { text-decoration:none }
<!--
label.error {color: red;}
.style2 {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
.style3 {font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace}
-->
</style>
<script>
var start = new Date();
</script>

</head>

<body class="font">
    <div class="account"><span class="boldfont">梦雨</span> | <a href="publish.php">发布公告</a> | <a href="account.php">帐户</a> | <a href="../common/logout.php">登出</a></div><a href="index.php"><img src="../common/logo.jpg" href="index.php" alt="Tenxian Logo" border=0 /></a>
<div class="steven"><a href="announcement.php?id=1">Ｕターンラッシュがピーク　新幹線や空の便、ほぼ満席</a><br/>
<label>总金额:</label><label class="price">$30.00</label>

<label>所需有效读者:100</label>
<label id="report" onclick="taskreport(1)" style="float:right;color:gray;font-size:8pt;cursor:pointer;">
举报</label>
<pre id="bodytext">

　年末年始をふるさとや行楽地で過ごした人たちのＵターンラッシュが３日、ピークを迎え、新幹線や空の便は午前中からほぼ満席となった。

　ＪＲ各社によると、東海道新幹線は上りの指定席が終日ほぼ満席で、博多から東京に向かうのぞみの自由席乗車率は、朝から１００％を超えた。東北・上越新幹線も上りの一部列車の自由席が満席になった。

　日航と全日空によると、羽田空港に向かう国内線の予約率は日航が９９％、全日空が９３％とほぼ満席状態。

　日本道路交通情報センターのまとめでは、東名高速道路上り線は３日午前９時半現在、浜松インターチェンジ（静岡県）付近で１８キロ、由比パーキングエリア（同）付近で１３キロの渋滞。渋滞は昼から夕方にかけて最も激しくなるとみられ、東名高速の大和トンネル（神奈川県）付近と、九州自動車道の八幡インター（福岡県）付近で、それぞれ４５キロ程度と予想されている。
</pre>
<label>当前余额:</label><label class="price">$29.40</label>
<label>价格/人:</label><span class="golden">$0.30</span>
不足: 98 <label style="float:right">发布者:梦雨</label>

<hr><label>合格者(2)</label><br/>  <label>test</label>  <label>我的名字</label><br/><br/>
<label>不合格者(0)</label><br/><hr><script>
var report_i=0;
function taskreport(id){
    if (report_i==1)
{
alert("请不要多次举报");
return;
}
$.post("taskreport.php",{taskid:id},function(xml){
if(xml.indexOf("Duplicate")==0)
{
alert("请不要多次举报");
return; 
} 
      alert(xml);
});
taskreport_i=1; 
}
</script><div>你当前的余额为<span style="color:red">860.50</span>元</div><br/>
<form id="digitalchange" action="digitalchange.php" method="post" onSubmit="return Adjust()">
<input type="hidden" name="tid" value=1 />
单价:$
<input id="unitpricetemp" name="unitpricetemp"  type="text" size="5" maxlength="6" value= 0.30 />&nbsp
不足:<input id="shortfalltemp" type="text"  name="shortfalltemp" size="4" maxlength="6" value=98 />

<input id="add_price" type="submit" value="提交"/></form><br/>
<form action="close.php?taskid=1" method="POST" onSubmit="return doublecheck()">
<input type="submit" title="关闭公告后，余额将返回到你的账户上。" value="关闭该公告"/>
</form>

<hr><script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#digitalchange").validate(
    { 
        rules: { 
        unitpricetemp: {
            required:true,
            number:true,
            min:0.1,
        },
         shortfalltemp: {
            required:true,
          digits:true,
            min:50,
            }
        },  
        messages: { 


        }
    }); 
 }); 
 var $balance=860.50;
function Adjust(){
var $totalprice=parseFloat($('#unitpricetemp').val())*parseInt($('#shortfalltemp').val());
  if($totalprice>$balance)
  {
  alert("Sorry, you do not have enough money on your account to make this adjustment.");
  return false;
  }
return true;

};
function doublecheck(){
    if(window.confirm('关闭后不能被开启。你一定要关闭该公告吗？'))
    {
    return true;    
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
</script><div>Q:年末年始をふるさとや行楽地で過ごした人たちのＵターンラッシュが３日</div>
<div>A:東海道</div><br/><div>Q:日航と全日空によると、羽田空港に向かう国内線の予約率は日航が９９％</div>
<div>A:新幹線</div><br/><div>Q:Google の ホームページにアクセスすると、いろいろな言語で情報を探したり</div>
<div>A. ウェブ検索(答案)    B. 特殊検索   C. 画像検索  D. ディレクトリ</div><br/><div>Q:Google のホームページにアクセスしなくてもこれらの情報を検索できる</div>

<div>A. ニュース(答案)    B. ブックス   C. ブログ検索  D. マップ</div><br/><a href="edit.php?id=1">编辑</a><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

 <div align="center">@2009 Tenxian      &nbsp;&nbsp;使用条款
</div><br/>
<div align="center"><a href="/en/bidding/index.php">Tenxian·English</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="/jp/bidding/index.php">腾闲·日本</a></div><br/><br/>


</div><div class="john">
<div>评论(2)<span style="float:right"> 从新到旧 </span></div><br/>  ３日から放送が始まったＮＨＫ大河ドラマ「龍馬伝」の初回視聴率が２３．２％（ビデオリサーチ調べ、関東地区）を記録、前年の「天地人」の初回視聴率２４．７％を下回った。<br/><br/>

<div style="float:right" class="black" >test 2010-01-04 22:37:07</div><br/><hr>   　第１回は、上士と郷士の激しい差別が続く土佐で、子供時代から青年へと成長した龍馬が平等な世を願う思いを持ち始めるというストーリー。<br/><br/>
<div style="float:right" class="black" >test 2010-01-04 22:34:28</div><br/><hr> <form id="form2" action="comment.php?id=1" method="post">
    <div>提交你的评论:</div>
<textarea id="textarea2" name="textarea2" rows="3" cols="29"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="提交"></form></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#form2").validate(
    { 
        rules: { 
         textarea2: {
            required: true,
             minlength:30,
             maxlength:500

        }
        }, 
          messages: { 


        }
    }); 
 }); 
</script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

A live example might be better than posting code, since you're referencing CSS files that don't exist when I view that HTML on my computer.

I don't see any underlines on the text, however there are several "horizontal rules" - maybe that is your problem? You'd just need to remove each of the `<hr>` tags in the HTML.